# How can I integrate an android app with expert systems using SWI-Prolog?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to build an *expert system* that runs on android. I am using *Android Studio* as my development tools and I already started to build the knowledge base using SWI-Prolog. I want to take the result from the prolog and show it in the android program. Do I need API or there is a direct way that I can communicate between the prolog and the android program ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's an interesting question but probably off-topic here. A good starting point is http://stackoverflow.com/a/8910073/3235496